# Setting the manufacturer in a VS 2008 Setup Project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, installation, windows-installer

I have a windows setup project that installs a service. All works well except for one thing: The default directory offered to the user during install is of the form "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\ProgramName". I am trying to modify this so that instead of "Microsoft" we would have our company's name.

I found the application folder property of the setup project, and it has a DefaultLocation property of "[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer][ProductName]".  So, it looks like all I need to do is set the "Manufacturer" property and I'll be all set.  However, I can not find a way to set this property!  I had hoped it would take it from the company name in the AssemblyInfo of the primary output project, but it did not.

I could remove "[Manufacturer]" from the DefaultLocation and replace it with our literal company name, but that seems like a hack.

How do I set the Manufacturer name?

Note that I am not using a full-blown WiX project.  I have simply added a windows setup project to my solution.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I have this same issue in VS2010.  Good question!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Click on your setup project in Visual Studio, open the Properties and you will notice that there are a number of Properties that you can set like Manufacturer, SupportURL, etc.

Comment: Wow! That did it. 

I had been right-clicking on the setup project and selecting "Properties".  That brings up a *different* window than left-clicking on the setup project and then clicking on the "Properties" tab.

I had always thought those methods were equivalent. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Rob.. I was banging my head since the last 20 minutes to find these options. I was also using right click > properties

Answer (score 13):

Note if you're confused/frustrated doing this seemingly trivial thing: if you open properties by right-clicking on the project and clicking "Properties" in the right-mouse menu, you will get the wrong dialog box.  You need to select the project, but then navigate to the properties tag.  One way to navigate to the properties tag is from the "View" menu, select "Properties Window".