# Where are the [ProgramFilesFolder][Manufaturer][ProductName] found?

Tags: windows-services, setup-project

In the article at [How do I set the default install path with a windows installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138363/how-do-i-set-the-default-install-path-with-a-windows-installer) the directions state to 'select the Setup project in Solution Explorer, and examine the properties grid to find them', where 'them' refers to [ProgramFilesFolder][Manufaturer][ProductName]. Doing this brings up a property pages dialog that has configuration properties but nowhere are there fields for setting these, [ProgramFilesFolder][Manufaturer][ProductName]. I tried attaching a screen shot but was unable. The project is written in C#, .Net 3.5 using VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the wrong properties dialog. Try the results of this thread.

[Setting the manufacturer in a VS 2008 Setup Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272717/setting-the-manufacturer-in-a-vs-2008-setup-project)

If you still have issues, post the screenshot.